# pick up all UIGestureRecognizer events in callback?

Tags: ios, uigesturerecognizer, uipangesturerecognizer, uitapgesturerecognizer, uipinchgesturerecognizer

Is there a way to pickup all UIGestureRecognizer events in one method?  (besides via directing all their selectors to the same method).

So for example:

```
    // Add Gesture Recogniser (Long Press)
    let longPressGR = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(GcMapView.longPressAction(_:)))
    longPressGR.minimumPressDuration = 1
    self.addGestureRecognizer(longPressGR)

    // Add Gesture Recogniser (Pan)
    let mapDragRecognizer =  UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(GcMapView.panAction(_:)))
    mapDragRecognizer.delegate = self
    self.addGestureRecognizer(mapDragRecognizer)

    // Add Gesture Recogniser (Pinch)
    let pinchGestureRecogniser =  UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(GcMapView.pinchAction(_:)))
    pinchGestureRecogniser.delegate = self
    self.addGestureRecognizer(pinchGestureRecogniser)    

   // SOME METHOD NOW TO PICKUP ALL EVENTS
   func PICKUPALLEVENTS (sender:UIGestureRecognizer) {
       print("(String(gestureRecognizer.dynamicType) - \(gestureRecognizer.state.hashValue) ")
   }
```

Comment: Please explain what you mean by "pickup". What information do you want that you could not get by making all of the gesture recognizers call the same action?

Comment: the info in the PICKUPALLEVENTS function (see above)

Comment: In a single action method, couldn't you keep an instance variable for each gesture recognizer, or iterate through `self.gestureRecognizers`, and call `dynamicType` and `state.hash` on each?

Comment: could - but I was interested in knowing if there was a method/callback that did what I've asked that I was missing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, I don't think there is any way to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding a `UIGestureRecognizer` to your target, then checking the dynamic type of the `UIGestureRecognizer` in the selector called?

Comment: good idea - actually lets me put this code in and builds, but nothing happens, so doesn't seem to work

Comment: Nothing happens as in it doesn't call the selector?

Comment: Oh well, then it seems you are out of luck. There is no native support for this unfortunately.